# php variable delegate functions

Tags: php

I have the following code and am trying to find a solution:

```
<?php

class t1 {

    public $response = array();
    public $request = array();

    public function getRequest() {
        return $this->request;
    }

    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

}

class t2 extends t1 {
    public function run($f) {
        $this->response = $f($this);
        return $this;
    }
}

$delegate = function($c)
{
    // PLACEHOLDER
    // This is the only place to update test code
    // It's not allowed to modify any other section of this code
};

$t = new t2();
print_r(array("request" => $t->run($delegate)->getRequest(), "response" => $t->getResponse()));
?>
```

I assume $delegate is a dynamic function. Anyone able to walk me through this.

I'm thinking in PLACEHOLDER is should be:

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume $delegate is a dynamic function.

Yes. `$delagate` is a PHP [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

If you define your function as:

```
$delegate = function($c)
{

};
```

and pass it to `$t->run`, then `$c` will be the `$t` instance.